# How to flatten a memoryview?

Tags: python, memoryview

I have a `memoryview` with non-trivial strides like the following:

```
>>> mv.strides
(96, 32, 8)
```

I want to write this `memoryview` to a socket but my networking library seems to expect memoryviews with `mv.strides == (1,)`.  Is there a way in Python to flatten this `memoryview`?

```
>>> flatten(mv).strides
(1,)
```

Ideally this would neither affect the underlying bytes nor require a copy. I *could* do this with NumPy, but I'd rather keep things general if possible.

#### Edit: Here is some code that produces such a memoryview

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: x = np.ones((2, 3, 4))
In [3]: x.data
Out[3]: <memory at 0x7f371aa849a8>

In [4]: x.data.strides
Out[4]: (96, 32, 8)
```

Comment: What's the source of this `memoryview`?  That's not a basic Python class or concept.  I only know of `cython's` of the term.

Comment: @hpaulj It's a python-concept: [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#func-memoryview). But it would be good to know for certain what `memoryview` were're talking about

Comment: Memoryviews are indeed part of Python.  They are commonly used by the numeric community.  My users often provide them as the result of numpy computations, but I'd prefer a solution that was not numpy-centric.

Comment: If you don't want a numpy-centric answer, add code that creates one using only things that are built-in to Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for clarification, you probably know this but I think it's better to make sure:

- The **length of the strides tuple** represents the number of dimensions, so `(1, )` and `(8, )` are both one dimensional and `(10, 2)` and `(20, 1)` are both two-dimensional.
- For C-contiguous arrays the last element in the strides tuple represents the itemsize of the items in your memoryview. That's not always correct: sometimes the values are padded then it will be bigger than the actual itemsize - but in most cases it represents the itemsize.

So you don't only want your memoryview flattened but it should be **flattened and have an itemsize of 1**.

In Python 3.3 the [`memoryview.cast`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.cast) method was added that makes flattening your array trivial:

> ### `cast(format[, shape])`
>
> Cast a memoryview to a new format or shape. shape defaults to [byte_length//new_itemsize], which means that the result view will be one-dimensional. The return value is a new memoryview, but the buffer itself is not copied. Supported casts are 1D -> C-contiguous and C-contiguous -> 1D.
>
> The destination format is restricted to a single element native format in struct syntax. One of the formats must be a byte format (‘B’, ‘b’ or ‘c’). The byte length of the result must be the same as the original length.

So it only works if you cast to char (`c`), unsigned char (`B`) or signed chars (`b`) and it's C-contiguous.

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> memview = memoryview(np.ones((2, 3, 4)))
>>> memview.cast('b').strides   # or 'B' or 'c'
(1, )
```

However this is flattened and interpreted as 1-byte values. If you just want it flattened you need to cast it to the original type again:

```
>>> memview.cast('b').cast(memview.format)
```

That will be one-dimensional but it won't have strides of `(1, )` because floats are 8 bytes (at least if it's `float64`):

```
>>> memview.cast('b').cast(memview.format).strides
(8, )
```

Comment: A sequence of `cast` calls works with nonbyte formats: `x.data.cast('B').cast('B',shape=[192]).cast('d')`.  But strides for 'd' is `(8,)`.  So strides of `(1,)` will require a compatible format.

Comment: @hpaulj Ah right, but It's even easier with `.cast('B').cast(memview.format)`. There's no need to specify the shape then.